# How do I pass parameters to an MySQL OdbcCommand and only How do I update only if a predicate matches?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

#### Question 1 - How do I correctly pass parameters to a MySQL OdbcCommand?

I am new to MYSQL.

I want to write update query.I have written like this but it is not working.

```
private int UpdateUser(ClsUserRegistrationProp ObjUserProp, int IntUesrId)
{
    Int32 Isdone;
    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ?,UserName = ?,Password = ?,EmailId = ? where UserId= ?", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OdbcType.Int).Value = IntUesrId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = ObjUserProp.FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = ObjUserProp.LastName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = ObjUserProp.UserName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = ObjUserProp.Password;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = ObjUserProp.EmailId;

        con.Open();

        Isdone=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        con.Close();
        return Isdone;




    }
}
```

#### Question 2 - How do I only update the record if the username or email matches?

Also I want to check username and email already exist or not.If they are not exist then and only then record will update

How can I do this?Please help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Parameters

If you use ODBC you must name your variables @xyz, so

```
UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = @FirstName, ... WHERE xyz
```

and add parameters like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", ...)
```

Just for completeness if you use the MySQL connectors the SQL should read

```
UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName = ?FirstName, ... WHERE xyz
```

and add parameters like this (without the '?'!)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", ...)
```

#### Username, Email Check

The basic approach would be to do a SELECT for the username and/or email and then only do the update if that returns no results, but there you can do it in one statement like this:

```
UPDATE tblUsers SET ... WHERE UserId= @userId AND Email = @Email AND UserName = @UserName
```

So the update will only work if email and username is the same as you pass into the parameters.

You can then use the int from ExecuteNonQuery to check if a record was changed (result > 0) or none was changed (result = 0). If none was changed, then email and username did not match. (Warning: If you pass in the wrong user id, this will also return result = 0!)

HTH
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like:

```
UPDATE tblUsers 
SET FirstName = @Firstname, LastName = @LastName,UserName = @UserName,Password = @Password,EmailId = @EmailId
WHERE UserId= @userId AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName=@UserName AND EmailId=@EmailId 
 )
```